# MySQL - Selecting random row without repeating

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a website that gets a random movie from database and then shows it to you. I want to select it without repeating(showing one movie few times while other movies aren't shown) and have it done in the fastest way.

This is what do I have:

```
$db = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword, $DBdatabase);
$offset_result = " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM database";
$result = $db->query($offset_result);
$offset_row = $result->fetch_object();
$offset = $offset_row->offset;

$db = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword, $DBdatabase);
$query = "SELECT id, title, year, front_image, category, watched, description, imdb_code, bg_image, scene_warning FROM database LIMIT $offset,1";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
list($id, $mtitle, $myear, $front_image, $category, $watched, $description, $imdb_code, $bg_image, $warning)=$stmt->fetch_row();
```

That is selecting but with repeating... Without repeating, I have this but it's slow.

```
$db = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword, $DBdatabase);
$query = "SELECT id, title, year, front_image, category, watched, description, imdb_code, bg_image, scene_warning FROM a358_filmovi WHERE id NOT IN (".$movies_array.") ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
list($id, $mtitle, $myear, $front_image, $category, $watched, $description, $imdb_code, $bg_image, $warning)=$stmt->fetch_row();
```

$movies_array is imploded session array which contains movie IDs.

**So, the question is, how to make a query same as first one (the fastest one) but with an array that contains IDs so movies won't repeat?**

Comment: Why not add a column to the database, say "Shown", and when you select a movie you set "Shown" = TRUE for that movie.  Then when you're doing your select query you can change it to only select from those where "Shown" = FALSE.  When all the movies have "Shown" = TRUE then you reset them all to FALSE to begin again - that way the difference between your most shown and least shown is only ever 1

Comment: @Kvothe That's a public website and anyone can access it so if a column is set to Shown = True then no one will be able to see that movie until all movies are shown.

Comment: Ah right, I thought the intention was for all the movies to be shown an equal number of times regardless of the person accessing (i.e. not specific to that user at that time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not pull all your ids first into a session array, choose a random index, look it up, then delete that index from the session array?

Comment: I like the idea. I will try it for sure.

Comment: This is the better idea; just get the ids, use `array_shuffle()` to randomize, store in session, then pop off the next to be shown. Much less effort than queries each time.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I used array_rand() to select a random id and then unset() to remove it from an array. When count(sessionarray) equals to 0, ids are taken from the database again. It works perfectly.